# PostgreSQL, Hibernate : Moving contents of db to text file/XML file for storage purposes

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, postgresql

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which we are seeing that the database is growing big. The space is consumed by chat messages history mostly, and other stuff like old notifications, which are not that useful.

Because of which we thought of moving the guys to some text/XML file to give the DB some room to breath and increase the performance of queries thereby. Indexes are not that useful as too many insertions.

I wanted to know if there is any way, PostgreSQL or Hibernate has support for such a task, where data is picked out of db and saved in plain files, which can be accessed and result in atleast good performance gains.

I have only started looking up some stuff, so I don't have much in hand to show. Kindly let me know if there are any questions you guys have.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The size of the database (especially the XML content) is only relevant if you actually select it. You are not using `select  *` all over the places are you? "*Indexes are not that useful as too many insertions*" - how do you know that? Did you run performance tests that showed that your inserts get unacceptable slow?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : Most of the places I am not using select *, I am using hibernate to give me back relevant data. I agree I have to retrieve data from XML too. No, that is what I have read, and as you can presume, chatmessages every second or so by a group is lot of insertions. Plus the notifications, they are bulk inserted.

Comment: Can't you tell your obfuscation layer ("Hibernate") to _not_ retrieve the XML columns or only when you explicitly request them? Regarding the indexes: do make tests. There is no way anyone can tell if the performance advantages of having the index outweigh the disadvantages. I have seen high insert rates on tables with over 10 indexes without problems - it all depends on your hardware and what is more important to you.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : One other option I was considering was to partition the tables, based on timeframe, like per 2 weeks or so.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : I can instruct Hibernate not to give me information from XML columns, but I wanted to know if PostgreSQL or Hibernate provides any mechanism to push data to a XML file? That is my question. Btw, even when I complain about indexes, we have them in place for now.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [`PostgreSQL` JSON storage](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) and have two databases:

- the current operations DB, the one where you are moving data away to slim it
- the archive database where old data is aggregated to save storage

This way you can move data from the current database into the archive database without compromising [ACID attributes](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-acid-and-database-transactions/) and you can aggregate the old data to simplify retrieval, by grouping various related entities based on some common root entity, which you'll then use to access your old data.

This way the current operation database remains small enough, while the archive database can be shared. This way, it's easier to configure the current operation for high performance, while the archive one for scalability.

Anyway, hibernate doesn't support this out-of-the-box, but you can implement it using custom Hibernate types and JTA transactions.

Comment: I would not use two separate databases because that way you can't query the archive and the current one with the same query. If at all I'd use two different schemas.

Comment: I agree with @a_horse_with_no_name . I am interested in querying the database too, when search results fail from first database, or when the user specifically requests old dataset.

Comment: That's not a requirement in the current question and it could be that newest data shouldn't be joined with older one. It always depend on the application data requirements, so there's silver bullet.

Comment: @We are Borg You can query against two different data sources, as long as you join data in the application layer. But if you wanted to JOIN newer and old data, storing the older one in XML file wouldn't help you either, so I guess there's still some missing info.

Comment: My idea was to store the data in XML and only ask the XML when the resultSet from database is empty or when user specifically requests old chat, by clicking again and again to go into older chats or notifications. But if I keep issuing join queries on both databases all the time, i don't think it will benefit me a lot.